Problem installing Opera Browser on Lenovo IdeaPad S145-15AST - Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Opera won't install from the snap store. Appears to but doesn't. It did install and run last week but stopped so I uninstalled it and now can't reinstall.
Tried in terminal too
error: cannot perform the following tasks:

Fetch and check assertions for snap "opera" (345) (cannot verify snap "opera", no matching signatures found)

Thanks
